# Greyhound Ticket Change $20 Fee for Military Personnel

Tags: buses

I was told greyhound was not supposed to charge military personnel $20.00 charge for changing tickets.  My son had a change to his orders and we had to change his bus tickets to a week later.

Comment: Should we infer that your son was in fact charged $20 and you're trying to find out if he can get it back somehow?  Or trying to find out whether the information you had was in fact correct?  Did you want to ask about something else related to this situation?

Comment: I was trying to find out if they should have charged him the $20.00 to change his tickets because he is active duty military personnel and his orders changed due to Hurricane Florence and other military parents said their Marine didn't get charged.. and they all had the same type of refundable tickets booked for them

Comment: What did Greyhound say when you asked?

Comment: 2 different agents.. one i couldn't understand but he said his bus was not cancelled and therefore i had to pay the $20 change fee.  Honestly IDK if the person knew what marine corps or military meant. Another one told me the $20.00 fee would have been waived if i went in person to a greyhound station to change them.  But because I called on the phone I had to pay $20.00 No rhyme or reason.   Other guy I talked to said his son changed his & had same change in orders reporting dates and no fee & he did his over the phone.

Answer (score 3):

There are just [two sets of terms and conditions for Greyhound tickets](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/travel-dilemmas/ticket-refunds-exchanges):

- **Non-refundable** but exchange but for $20 fee.
- **Refundable** and exchangeable for free.

It seems the military discount may be applicable to either type.

I had a look through their National Promotional Fares and Programs in the [Passenger Fare Sales Manual](http://extranet.greyhound.com/revsup/pfsm/pageset.html) (intended for their ticket agents' use). Page 9.5 on the military discount states:

> REFUND: Standard refund policy applies

Since the refund and exchange policies are always linked and one of the two options above, it seems the fee would depend of the type of ticket purchased regardless of military discount.

---

You commented:

> and they all had the same type of *refundable* tickets booked for them

So it seems you should not have been charged the fee, if the tickets were indeed refundable.

Comment: I checked the Greyhound site and indeed the page describing the types of fares make no mention of any exemption from change fee for military personnel.  Perhaps there used to be such an exemption.  There *is* a 10% discount, but the page describing that also makes no mention of other benefits such as reduced or waived change fees.

Comment: Had a look in Greyhounds ticketing handbook. It's not the easiest document to understand but it also makes no mention of a special rule.

Comment: I seriously think it depends on who you get on the phone, because I know for a fact other marine corps active duty guys who had tickets had theirs changed and they waved the $20.00 fee.

Comment: And the military base in parris island intentionally books refundable tickets because of the fact their orders could change at any given time

Comment: Indeed it sounds like someone made a mistake. If they book refundable tickets, there should be no $20 exchange fee (military discount or not). This is not because it's a waiver, it's the terms of the tickets Greyhound agreed to.

Comment: @Cris *nobody*.with a refundable ticket is supposed to pay a fee.  It's the *non-refundable* tickets that are subject to a $20 change fee.  If the tickets really were refundable then anyone who had to pay a fee should complain, military or not.

Comment: I agree.  I just don't know if I have it in me again to go through the hassle of calling and getting yet another person who I can't understand (because their english is so terrible) or gives me the run around again and yet a 3rd answer different from the first two answers.

Comment: It may be worth trying to contact them on Facebook [or Twitter](https://twitter.com/ghoundbushelp). It's often a different support team that handles social media requests, and they may be sensitive to the fact that charging a change fee to a service member who received orders due to a hurricane looks rather bad. And if nothing else, it can be less irritating than talking on the phone yet again.

Comment: @Cris if you don't have it in you to call, maybe there's an address you can write to.  Carl might know.  If there is, and you send them a letter laying out all the facts (copies of refundable ticket, changed reservations, new ticket, receipt or statement showing payment of $20 fee), they might send a refund, or at least a coherent explanation of what happened.  Also consider Zach Lipton's suggestion.

Comment: @phoog yes, they do accept claims to the mailing address on their website https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/contact-us. (They don't have a support  email.) You might also try to speak to the agent at a local greyhound station in person.

Comment: Just posted on greyhound FB page.  Unfortunately as the nite goes on my mood goes south even quicker so my comments reflected such. Maybe someone will be monitoring the page and respond.  Thank you everyone for your help.  Heck it would have been cheaper and quicker for him to fly but my son said Corps purposely books bus tickets because they frequently can have orders changed and the bus tickets can be changed. Hmmm!  After reading so many negative reviews about Greyhound I just hope he makes it there on time without any bobbles.

Comment: no answer back from greyhound via Facebook.  of course not!